# Activity screen goes blank while loading soundpools

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am loading around 100 soundpools of small sound which I need them through out application in an activity.
When this activity starts, the screen goes blank and the background loads after loading all soundpools.

How do make it display the background I which have already added in xml through out while loading soundpools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use AsyncTask to handle this.

```
private class MyBackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //initialize views like progress dialog.
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        //Add code which you want to run in background.
        //In your case, code to load sound pools
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostExecute(Boolean success) {
        //update UI with the result
    }
}
```

And in onCreate method,

```
new MyBackgroundTask().execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. :)
I'll try to implement it and get back here.
In mean while if can can give me any links to examples on AsyncTask would help me a lot.

Comment: check out this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#asynctask